# C can't compile - symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, compilation

Having a serious problem with my C code, I just don't seem to be able to get it to compile and I really can't figure out why.

I have tried researching online and can't find a solution to the problem, do you have any idea?

Thanks for your time!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Insert", referenced from:
      _InsertNode in part1.o
     (maybe you meant: _InsertNode)
  "_Create", referenced from:
      _findShortestPaths in part1.o
  "_DeleteMin", referenced from:
      _findShortestPaths in part1.o
  "_decreaseKey", referenced from:
      _findShortestPaths in part1.o
  "_GetMin", referenced from:
      _findShortestPaths in part1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [part1] Error 1
```

Snippits from part1.c

```
#include "limits.h"
#include "pegBinaryHeap.h"

void InsertNode(int distance, Node* node, PriorityQueue PQ) {
  ...
  Insert(*item, PQ);
}

...

int* findShortestPaths(Graph *graph, int start) {
  ...

  //Priority queue ordered by distance
  PriorityQueue pq = Create(graph->MaxSize);
  for(int i = 0; i < graph->MaxSize; i++) {
    ...
  }

  //While the queue isn't empty:
  while((currentPqItem=GetMin(pq)) != NULL) { 
    ...
    DeleteMin(pq);

      //for each node accesable from currentNode
    List *currentNeighbour = currentNode.outlist;

    while(currentNeighbour!=NULL) {
      ...
        decreaseKey(currentNode.id, newDistance, pq);
    } // end for
  }// end while
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  Graph mygraph;
  return 0;
}
```

And the .h file that it appears to be complaining about

```
#include "graph.h"

struct HeapStruct;
typedef struct HeapStruct *PriorityQueue;

typedef struct {
  int distance;
  Node *node;
} QueueType;

PriorityQueue Create( int MaxSize );
void Destroy( PriorityQueue H );
int Insert( QueueType Item, PriorityQueue H );
QueueType DeleteMin( PriorityQueue H );
QueueType* GetMin( PriorityQueue H );
void decreaseKey(int nodeId, int value, PriorityQueue H);
```

Comment: Where is the `.c` file containing the functions it's complaining about (`Insert`, `Create`, etc.)?

Comment: In the same folder "pegBinaryHeap.c"

Comment: Please post the command you use to compile the code.

Comment: "part1: part1.o graph_functions.o pegBinaryHeap.o"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can *compile*, but you cannot *link*.

`part1.o` is using the functions you defined in your last `.h` file and the implementations cannot be found.  When you link your program, you need to make sure you're linking in the object file(s) (or libraries) that contain the implementations of those functions.  You've likely done something like:

`gcc part1.c -o myapp`

and so the linker doesn't have all the pieces to the puzzle.

If you want to compile in parts, you need to:

```
gcc -c part1.c -o part1.o
gcc -c implementations.c -o implementations.o 
gcc implementations.o part1.o -o myapp
```

Here, all the `.c` files are compiled into object (`.o`) files separately, and then linked together into an executable.  Or you could do everything at once:

```
gcc part1.c implementations.c -o myapp
```

If the implementations are in a library (`libimplementations.a`):

```
gcc part1.c -Lpath/to/libs -limplementations -o myapp
```

Comment: Accepted as although you didn't give the answer, you have a very clear explanation that improved my understanding of c header and object files!

Comment: @greg any particular reason why C code would use C++ compiler? It's doable but it often leads to weird warnings/compiler errors. Also it's heck a lot slower (compilation time).

Comment: @AoeAoe writing g++ instead of gcc was a typo (I was writing C++ all morning).  Editing it now, though the concepts I was trying to explain are exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add I was getting a similar compilation error. See below.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_add", referenced from:
   _load in file.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I solved this issue by implementing the add() functions prototype that I had created in my header file. Once implemented I did not receive this error anymore. May help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try creating a minimalistic example that shows the same error. We are missing too much information to help you diagnose this. The code in the other files and the actual compilation commands (not just a part of a Makefile but the actual commands) might be the source of this problem.

(yes, this should be a comment rather than an answer, but I'm not able to comment on questions for some reason)